# Как посчитать на ежемесяной основе используя Groupby + agg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

Как посчитать на ежемесячной основе с помощью Groupby + agg   сумму по общей стоимость заказа TotalCost, кол-во уникальных клиентов CustomerID, кол-во заказов (уникальные по полю InvoiceNo)

```
InvoiceNo   StockCode   Description Quantity    InvoiceDate UnitPrice   CustomerID  Country TotalCost
0   536365  85123A  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER  6   2010-12-01 08:26:00 2.55    17850.0 United Kingdom  15.30
1   536365  71053   WHITE METAL LANTERN 6   2010-12-01 08:26:00 3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom  20.34
2   536365  84406B  CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER  8   2010-12-01 08:26:00 2.75    17850.0 United Kingdom  22.00
3   536365  84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE 6   2010-12-01 08:26:00 3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom  20.34
4   536365  84029E  RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.  6   2010-12-01 08:26:00 3.39    17850.0 United Kingdom  20.34
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
csv файл drive.google.com/open?id=13qNaA3BV3aVhwYf89xok8ejucO8zNKAD

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',  encoding='cp1250')
data4 = data
data4["InvoiceDate"] = pd.to_datetime(data4['InvoiceDate'])
data4.loc[:,'TotalCost'] = data4.loc[:,'Quantity'] * data4.loc[:,'UnitPrice']

data4.set_index('InvoiceDate').resample('M')["TotalCost"].sum(
data4.set_index('InvoiceDate').resample('M')["CustomerID"].count()
data4.set_index('InvoiceDate').resample('M')["InvoiceNo"].count()
```

Вопросы у меня: как сделать с groupby, получились ли у меня уникальные данные как в задании благодаря groupby или надо делать с nunique() , если да, то как?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [84]: funcs = dict(CustomerID="nunique", InvoiceNo="nunique", TotalCost="sum")

In [85]: data4.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="InvoiceDate", freq="MS")).agg(funcs)
Out[85]:
             CustomerID  InvoiceNo    TotalCost
InvoiceDate
2010-12-01          948       2025   748957.020
2011-01-01          783       1476   560000.260
2011-02-01          798       1393   498062.650
2011-03-01         1020       1983   683267.080
2011-04-01          899       1744   493207.121
2011-05-01         1079       2162   723333.510
2011-06-01         1051       2012   691123.120
2011-07-01          993       1927   681300.111
2011-08-01          980       1737   682680.510
2011-09-01         1302       2327  1019687.622
2011-10-01         1425       2637  1070704.670
2011-11-01         1711       3462  1461756.250
2011-12-01          686       1015   433668.010
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересно сделано.

Comment: красиво сделано